# git tool to alert teammates while editing files

Tags: git, github, slack

When working in a directory that is backed by git, big merge conflicts can be exhausting to resolve. If one member of a team could have a notification that another was editing a specific file, she would could wait until later. This could make for an easier way to avoid editing the same file simultaneously.

I am aware that developers could (and should) edit things in their own branches or forks. Yet when it is time to unify the code once again, it can be cumbersome to always stay in communication with which files are being edited by which team-member.

---

Has a tool like this been thought of or tried before?

I am imagining an Atom plugin which does a `POST` to a Slack group using a method like their API's `postMessage` [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage).

Comment: That's not how distributed VCS works. If you want that, you need a centralised VCS that supports exclusive checkouts (e.g. TFS).

Comment: Totally agree with @adrianbanks, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_version_control_software for a list of version control systems; you want one with "lock" or "merge or lock" in the "Concurrency Model" column.

Comment: [off-topic] This question brings back memories of SVN, thanks for ruining my morning, LOL